# Passing Active Directory Credentials to Jenkins API

Tags: c#, winforms, jenkins

I have a question about passing Active Directory credentials to Jenkins via the API. I have the AD plugin installed on the Jenkins server. However, we have a Windows forms application that we use to interact with Jenkins via the API. Currently, it is just using a default user and password for everyone. We want to change this. I have attempted to use `CredentialCache.DefualtNetworkCredentials`

The developer who implemented the original system is just encoding the UN and PW together, and passing them through the headers. I don't know much about the Jenkins API either and find there is not much in terms of documentation. Whenever I try and encode the credentials from the `DefaultNetworkCredentials` it ends up blank. Is there an easy was to pass the username and password in an encoded string to the API or is there a better way that someone knows? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I don't even need to encode the `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` I just need to send them across in the header itself. Seems to work.